# about the number Literals lexical

Tags: javascript, numbers, lexical

alert(010),the result is 8. why?
i read the ecmascript 7.8.3 Numeric Literals.
According to the Numeric Literals Lexical,
010 is a invalid numeric literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only so when strict mode is turned on :

```
(function(){
"use strict";
010;
})();
SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
```

Otherwise it would break backwards compatibility.

Comment: do you mean ecmascript dose not define the octal of the Numeric Literals,it is an extra extension of the js engine?

Comment: @user1039304 yes it's an extension in current ecmascript and it is only allowed in non strict mode at that.

Answer (score 0):

`010` in octal is `8` in decimal. If it says it's invalid (where's the link?), it may have changed, or you're doing it in a different version that isn't "ECMAScript" or something?

In many programming languages, an `0` before a numeric literal makes it octal.

Comment: the ecmascript dose not define the octal of the Numeric Literals.
so i think 010 is a invalid numeric literal